# Unable to convert CIImage to UIImage in Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, swift3, ciimage

I am making image form `QR Code` by using following code:

```
  func createQRFromString(str: String) -> CIImage? {
        let stringData = str.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator")

        filter?.setValue(stringData, forKey: "inputMessage")

        filter?.setValue("H", forKey: "inputCorrectionLevel")

        return filter?.outputImage
    }
```

And Then I am adding to `UIImageView` Like this:

```
    if let img = createQRFromString(strQRData) {
        let somImage = UIImage(CIImage: img, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.Down)
        imgviewQRcode.image = somImage
    }
```

Now I need to save this to a `JPEG` or `PNG` file. But when I am doing so my app crashes:

```
    @IBAction func btnSave(sender: AnyObject) {

    //        // Define the specific path, image name
    let documentsDirectoryURL = try! NSFileManager().URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: true)
    // create a name for your image
    let fileURL = documentsDirectoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("image.jpg")

    if let image = imgviewQRcode.image // imgviewQRcode is UIImageView
    {

        if let path = fileURL?.path
        {
            if !NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(fileURL!.path!)
            {
                if UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)!.writeToFile(path, atomically: true)
                {
                    print("file saved")
                }

            }//Checking existing file

        }//Checking path

    }//CHecking image

}
```

**Crash Point**

```
  UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)!.writeToFile(path, atomically: true)
```

**Reason**

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Debug Tests:

[image]

Answer (score 64, accepted):

```
func convert(cmage:CIImage) -> UIImage
{       
    let context:CIContext = CIContext.init(options: nil)
    let cgImage:CGImage = context.createCGImage(cmage, from: cmage.extent)!        
    let image:UIImage = UIImage.init(cgImage: cgImage)        
    return image
}
```

Use this function to convert CIImage to UIImage . It works .

Comment: @Shenona what should I pass in this method

Comment: This method requires CIImage . As per the post you are having trouble converting CIImage to UIImage . This method is having parameter which requires CIImage and returns UIImage .

Comment: @Shemona why this method is not releasing memory?

Answer (score 5):

```
 func convert(image:CIImage) -> UIImage
 {           
    let image:UIImage = UIImage.init(ciImage: image)        
    return image
 }
```

Perhaps, this was unavailable before, but it is now possible to create UIImages directly from CIImage.

Comment: Intriguing, but for some reason nil when I use this instead of context.createCGImage(myCIImage, from:rect)

Comment: I also get no output via UIImage(ciImage:), whereas I do get something from context.createCGImage()

Answer (score 4):

My final code

```swift
func generateQRCode(from string: String) -> UIImage? {
    let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.ascii)
            
    if let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator") {
        filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
        let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 3, y: 3)
                
        if let output = filter.outputImage?.transformed(by: transform) {
            let context:CIContext = CIContext.init(options: nil)
            let cgImage:CGImage = context.createCGImage(output, from: output.extent)!
            let image:UIImage = UIImage.init(cgImage: cgImage)
            return image
        }
    }
            
    return nil
}
```