# CIImage from UIImage return nil

Tags: ios, swift, ciimage

I have uiImage which is backed by a CIImage and its ciImage property is not nil. However if I create a new ciImage from this uiImage, it seems it is nil. Yes I know that I can directly use uiImage.ciImage property but I just wonder why this one fails. Any help please? I also need good references explaining all this apple image formats internals and details, good documents or links are welcome!
Edit : This question is not a dublicate of since it is pointing a problem in UIImage to CIImge conversion, not reverse.

```
    if uiImage.ciImage == nil {
        fatalError() // this one passes
    }

    let ciNew = CIImage(image: uiImage)

    if ciNew == nil {
        fatalError() // this gives fatal error !?
    }
```

Comment: Why are you doing that? `uiImage.ciImage` is the CIImage. Just use it.

Comment: You may want to refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40939075/unable-to-convert-ciimage-to-uiimage-in-swift-3-0

Comment: @Bappaditya yes but I am wondering why Apple provided method does not work?